# insert on conflict(guid) do batch update using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate doesnt work

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbctemplate, upsert, batch-updates

I am using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate and I want to do a batch update using the on conflict sql statement

```
sql = "INSERT INTO bl_crm_activity_line (guid,hdr_guid) VALUES (:guid, :hdr_guid,)
        ON CONFLICT (guid) DO UPDATE  SET guid = :guid, hdr_guid = :hdr_guid"
```

The query works fine for 1 insert or update:

```
Map<String, Object> m = objectMapper.convertValue(object, Map.class);
jdbcTemplate.update(query, m);
```

But when I do batch update with a list of that object(i tried two ways):

OPTION 1

> ```
> Map<String, Object>[] mapsToStore = objsToStore.stream().map(x -> convertObjectToMap(x)).toArray(HashMap[]::new); 
> this.jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, mapsToStore);
>
>
> public Map<String, Object> convertObjectToMap(Object objToStore) {
>       Map<String, Object> m = objectMapper.convertValue(objToStore, Map.class);
>       return m;
>   }
> ```

OPTION 2

> ```
>   SqlParameterSource[] batch =
>  SqlParameterSourceUtils.createBatch(objectList.toArray());
>          jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(query, batch);
> ```

both option 1 and 2 throws this error

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: start 468, end 242, s.length() 470
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:539)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:175)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.BatchedQuery.buildNativeSql(BatchedQuery.java:162)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.BatchedQuery.getNativeSql(BatchedQuery.java:84)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendParse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1370)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendOneQuery(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1729)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.sendQuery(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1294)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeBatch(PgStatement.java:793)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeBatch(PgPreparedStatement.java:1659)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:966)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:633)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:662)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:950)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.executeBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(NamedParameterBatchUpdateUtils.java:40)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:335
```

Not sure what am i doing wrong. Please assist

Comment: Why you have extra comma in `VALUES (:guid, :hdr_guid,)` ?

Comment: oops sorry ignore that..thats a typo here..not in the code itself